# Haskell: How to split a list of elements into several lists [a]->[[a]]

Tags: list, haskell, split

I have a given Int (example: 3) and a list of elements.

I want to sort these elements in 3 lists (depending on the given int).

For example: `3 [a,b,c,d,e,f,g] -> [[a,d,g],[b,e],[c,f]]`

I just know the function:

```
chunksOf 3 ['a'..'z']
["abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqr","stu","vwx","yz"]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not particularly clear why you'd reach the output `[[a,d,g],[b,e],[c,f]]` from the input, could you explain further?

Comment: The first element goes to the first list, the second to the socond list and the third to the third and then its starts from the beginning, the fourth element goest to the first list and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [transpose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose):

```
transpose ["abc", "def", "g"]
```

gives

```
["adg","be","cf"]
```

You can combine it

```
transpose $ chunksOf 3 "abcdefg"
```